# rails and jquery datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Using http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ for editing date time fields.  When I click the input field, the date time picker opens correctly.  The date is selected, but the time is not.  Time is always 00:00.  How can I pass the time from the input field to the datetimepicker?

Standard form_for

```
<%= f.text_field :closed_date, :class => "created-at-datetime" %>
```

and application.js

```
$('.created-at-datetime').datetimepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd ', timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss ', ampm: false});
```

Renders something like this:

```
<input class="created-at-datetime" id="order_closed_date" name="order[closed_date]" size="30" type="text" value="2011-04-06 21:47:12.985379" />
```

Comment: Seems to me the time format should be all one format ie: yy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss  I could be wrong but I havent seen it separated.  I know if the format is not right it will not go into a database

Comment: Brad, thanks.  Changed my input field to display time as Year-Month-Day and time to Hour:Min am/pm. So now it looks like 2011-04-11 09:13 am.  On the js datetimepicker I just have '$('.created-at-datetime').datetimepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd ', ampm: true});'.  Post your response as an answer to get credit.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me the time format should be all one format ie: yy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss I could be wrong but I havent seen it separated. I know if the format is not right it will not go into a database